# subversion hook template for access control on windows

Tags: windows, svn, svn-hooks

I set up a subversion server with bitnami stack for subversion on windows XP operating system. It was for local network and i would like to control steal lock and break lock abilities in accessing the repo. I changed pre-lock.tmpl and pre-unlock.tmpl to executable but it still is not working yet. It worked well when i tested it on linux system for bitnami stack. When i peeked into the template script, the script is for linux system. Can i get the script to work on windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

The hook scripts in Windows are Batch files, not .EXE executables.  The hook scripts should be changed to <*name*>.bat, e.g. `pre-unlock.bat`

Code the .bat file just like you would any other Windows CMD.EXE script.